# Upgrading from Glassfish 3.1.1 to 5.0.0, Java 7 to Java 8 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/Payload

Tags: java, java-8, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, glassfish-5

I have a Java EE (javaee-api v6) application currently running (and has been for years) in a java 7/glassfish 3.1.1 environment. I need it to run in java 8/glassfish 5.0.0. It uses maven to build, no build errors.

I am able to deploy the application (without modifications) to the new environment (java 8, gf 5) and it appears to work. I can login (ldap) and I can navigate the ui. The problem occurs when I try to run one of the java ee app clients (called a scheduler) that the application relies on.

Stack trace on execution of app client on startup:

```
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/Payload
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache.compute(LRUHybridCache.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperImpl.getAllFields(ClassReflectionHelperImpl.java:113)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.findInitializerFields(Utilities.java:1498)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.DefaultClassAnalyzer.getFields(DefaultClassAnalyzer.java:118)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getInitFields(Utilities.java:251)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:157)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:180)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.internalReify(SystemDescriptor.java:740)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:694)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:464)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.narrow(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2310)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.access$1200(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:128)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1395)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1390)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.internal.WeakCARCacheImpl.compute(WeakCARCacheImpl.java:128)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1452)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1377)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1366)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.secondChanceResolve(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:485)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1314)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:773)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:740)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:727)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.node.DeploymentDescriptorNode.getExtensionHandler(DeploymentDescriptorNode.java:318)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.node.DeploymentDescriptorNode.handlesElement(DeploymentDescriptorNode.java:411)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.node.SaxParserHandler.startElement(SaxParserHandler.java:501)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:743)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3132)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:852)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:318)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:245)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readStandardDeploymentDescriptor(Archivist.java:679)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:391)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:271)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:280)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.FacadeLaunchable.selectFacadeFromGroup(FacadeLaunchable.java:391)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.FacadeLaunchable.newFacade(FacadeLaunchable.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.Launchable$LaunchableUtil.newLaunchable(Launchable.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainerBuilder.newContainer(AppClientContainerBuilder.java:165)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.createContainerForAppClientArchiveOrDir(AppClientFacade.java:458)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.createContainer(AppClientFacade.java:417)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.prepareACC(AppClientFacade.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.agent.AppClientContainerAgent.premain(AppClientContainerAgent.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/Payload
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.get(LRUHybridCache.java:164)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache.compute(LRUHybridCache.java:303)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/Payload
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities$4.run(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities$4.run(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:115)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.secureGetDeclaredFields(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.getDeclaredFieldWrappers(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.getAllFieldWrappers(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperImpl$4.compute(ClassReflectionHelperImpl.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperImpl$4.compute(ClassReflectionHelperImpl.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(LRUHybridCache.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(LRUHybridCache.java:111)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(LRUHybridCache.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache.compute(LRUHybridCache.java:292)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.Payload
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 88 more
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Errors were discovered while reifying SystemDescriptor(
    implementation=com.sun.enterprise.config.modularity.ConfigModularityJustInTimeInjectionResolver
    contracts={com.sun.enterprise.config.modularity.ConfigModularityJustInTimeInjectionResolver,org.glassfish.hk2.api.JustInTimeInjectionResolver}
    scope=javax.inject.Singleton
    qualifiers={}
    descriptorType=CLASS
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=
    rank=0
    loader=null
    proxiable=null
    proxyForSameScope=null
    analysisName=null
    id=189
    locatorId=0
    identityHashCode=765826899
    reified=false)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:705)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:464)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.narrow(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2310)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.access$1200(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:128)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1395)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1390)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.internal.WeakCARCacheImpl.compute(WeakCARCacheImpl.java:128)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1452)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1377)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1366)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.secondChanceResolve(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:485)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1314)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:773)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:740)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:727)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.node.DeploymentDescriptorNode.getExtensionHandler(DeploymentDescriptorNode.java:318)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.node.DeploymentDescriptorNode.handlesElement(DeploymentDescriptorNode.java:411)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.node.SaxParserHandler.startElement(SaxParserHandler.java:501)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:743)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3132)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:852)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:318)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:245)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readStandardDeploymentDescriptor(Archivist.java:679)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:391)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:271)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:280)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.FacadeLaunchable.selectFacadeFromGroup(FacadeLaunchable.java:391)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.FacadeLaunchable.newFacade(FacadeLaunchable.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.Launchable$LaunchableUtil.newLaunchable(Launchable.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainerBuilder.newContainer(AppClientContainerBuilder.java:165)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.createContainerForAppClientArchiveOrDir(AppClientFacade.java:458)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.createContainer(AppClientFacade.java:417)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.prepareACC(AppClientFacade.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.agent.AppClientContainerAgent.premain(AppClientContainerAgent.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
```

It appears to be failing before it even starts executing the application logic, so I can't pinpoint the line of code where it's failing.

I thought maybe the application wasn't deploying correctly so I checked what modules/components had been deployed in glassfish (Applications -> my_app). I discovered there are a lot fewer components deployed in the java 8/gf 5 environment.

From env1, where it's working, java 7, gf 3.1.1: ~450 components

From env2, where it's broken, java 8, gf 5.0.0: ~150 components

Could this be the root cause? I am confused about how these components work. In the working environment there are duplicate components. For example:

```
Module Name                    Component Name
app-ejb.jar                    MyComponentFacade
app-war.war                    MyComponentFacade
app-ws.war                     MyComponentFacade
etc
```

In the new environment there are no duplicates.

I checked the glassfish logs during deployment but I am not seeing an obvious error there. I'll try to add the log to this post, not sure how at the moment.

Googling the javax/validation/Payload error lead me to believe there might be a conflict in the version of javax.validation-api it is using. There are 40+ poms in this project but this dependency is only in one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    <classifier>sources</classifier>
</dependency>
```

I've tried using different versions of this dependency with no success. The application also uses the gwt-user dependency which requires the validation-api, there could be a conflict there as well but I'm not sure.

I spent so much time on this I eventually decided to try the current version of Payara instead just to see if there was any difference. It failed the exact same way that glassfish 5 did.

I've tried updating the javaee-api version as well, didn't make a difference.

I don't know how to approach this problem.

EDIT:

I was able to get ride of the Payload error by adding the validation-api jar to my appclient directory (which exists outside of the glassfish directory).

Now I am getting:

```
2020/07/15 10:10:24 (Error -1)
Failure.
 
java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446346 Maybe; nested exception is:
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: 00810010: Error from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 10 completed: Maybe
CORBA MARSHAL 1330446346 Maybe; nested exception is:
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: 00810010: Error from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 10 completed: Maybe
WARNING: 00810010: Error from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream
Java heap space
 
javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446346 Maybe; nested exception is:
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: 00810010: Error from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 10 completed: Maybe
    at ca.company.something.engine.server._SystemParameterFacadeRemote_Wrapper.getMap(ca/company/something/engine/server/_SystemParameterFacadeRemote_Wrapper.java)
    at ca.company.something.engine.client.ClientSession.setUp(ClientSession.java:210)
    at ca.company.something.my_app.client.scheduler.SchedulerClientSession.setUp(SchedulerClientSession.java:85)
    at ca.company.something.my_app.scheduler.Scheduler.setUp(Scheduler.java:85)
    at ca.company.something.my_app.scheduler.Main.main(Main.java:123)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.launch(AppClientContainer.java:446)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.launch(AppClientFacade.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientGroupFacade.main(AppClientGroupFacade.java:65)
Caused by: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446346 Maybe; nested exception is:
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: 00810010: Error from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 10 completed: Maybe
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.mapSystemException(Util.java:267)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:201)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:226)
    at ca.company.something.engine.server.__SystemParameterFacadeRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.getMap(ca/company/something/engine/server/__SystemParameterFacadeRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: 00810010: Error from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 10 completed: Maybe
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.valuehandlerReadError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:828)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:921)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:518)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl$14.read(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:383)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.readResult(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:482)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:191)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.getConvertedChars(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:2083)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.internalReadString(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:469)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readStringOrIndirection(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:455)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_repositoryId(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1711)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_repositoryIds(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1693)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRepositoryIds(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:804)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRepositoryIds(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:769)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:870)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:518)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2091)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2333)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.defaultReadObjectDelegate(IIOPInputStream.java:525)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.InputStreamHook.defaultReadObject(InputStreamHook.java:233)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.readObject(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1438)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/196340990.invokeVirtual_LL_V(LambdaForm$DMH)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$BMH/109673034.reinvoke(LambdaForm$BMH)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH/1384626783.invoke_MT(LambdaForm$MH)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1764)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1146)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:350)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:311)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:277)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:819)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:921)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:518)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl$14.read(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:383)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.readResult(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:482)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:191)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:226)
    at ca.company.something.engine.server.__SystemParameterFacadeRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.getMap(ca/company/something/engine/server/__SystemParameterFacadeRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
    at ca.company.something.engine.server._SystemParameterFacadeRemote_Wrapper.getMap(ca/company/something/engine/server/_SystemParameterFacadeRemote_Wrapper
```